# Spring bean configuration for EnumMap

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, enum-map

```
public enum TypeEnum {
    TYPE1, TYPE2, TYPE3;
    }



public class Resources {
    List<String> suppliers;
    EnumMap<TypeEnum, String> items;

    //setter and getter

    }
```

I'm in the process of replicating the above bean in spring config xml file. I'm trying as per below but struck up with EnumMap. I understand that we can try using util:map. Please help.

```
<bean name="products" class="com.company.xxxx.Resources">

    <property name="suppliers">
        <list>
            <value>suppliers1</value>
            <value>suppliers2</value>
            <value>suppliers3</value>
        </list>
    </property>

    //TODO
    <util:map id="items" >

     </util:map>

</bean>
```

Comment: Nobody uses XML configuration anymore.  Use Spring Boot and configure that bean in code.  It'll be trivial.

Comment: I'm trying that approach for unit testing on my existing application.